# PayPalアカウントなしでクレジットカードで決済する方法はありますか、どう設定するのか

Tags: paypal

PayPal支払い画面で、支払方法を選択する場所に、ある時は、「PayPalアカウントから支払う」と「クレジットカードで支払う」になり、ある時は「PayPalアカウントから支払う」と「PayPalアカウントの作成」になります。その表示が変わる原因はなんでしょうか。
またパラメータなどを設定することで「クレジットカードで支払う」の表示で固定する方法はありますか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPalのウェブサイトペイメントスタンダードまたはエクスプレスチェックアウトを利用している場合、PayPalの仕様としては、必ずゲストチェックアウト（PayPalアカウントなしにクレジットカード決済）できることではございません。

直接クリジットカードで支払うできるかどうかはPayPalサーバーから判定されます、
その決済にリスクがあると判断されたら、詐欺などを防ぐために、強制的アカウント作成が要求される場合があります。

判断結果に影響する要素は、例えば売り手の国、買い手のIPの地域、ブラウザのクッキー、端末の種類、支払いの時間、ほかにもいろいろあります。
ただ、具体的な判断基準はPayPal内部情報、非公开となっています。

PayPalでは、ウェブペイメントプラス(Website Payments Plus)という直接クレジットカード決済をサポートしているサービスがあります。
ウェブペイメントプラスの場合、取引ごとの手数料以外に、月額手数料があります、具体的には下記のページを参考してください。
https://www.paypal.com/jp/webapps/mpp/webpayment-plus
導入ガイド：
https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/ja_JP/developer/docs/pdf/paymentsplus_jp.pdf

PayPalではテクニカルサポートの部署がありますので、何かPayPal実装関連の質問や技術的な質問がありましたら、下記URLで記事を検索してみてください。
https://jp.paypal-techsupport.com/
上記URLの一番下の「お問い合わせ」リンクをクリックしてまたは下記URLをアクセスして質問を送信してください。
https://jp.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask